# Invisible flow from an adminstrator?

Tags: visual-workflow

When editing a record, I am getting the below error:

> The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A
>   flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID
>   301w0000000Gufm. Flow error messages: **An unhandled fault has
>   occurred in this flow**
> An unhandled fault has occurred while
>   processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more
>   information. Contact your administrator for help.

But interestingly, this flow doesn't show up in my flow list: 
[image]

Note I have only one flow here in all flows view. And it is not the flow I am looking for.

Aside from it, I can open the flow by directly putting the id into the url: 
https://eu3.salesforce.com/designer/designer.apexp#Id=301w0000000Gufm

But I am wondering why I am unable to see that flow in my list. I am an administrator so it is a little bit weird.

Comment: 301 is the flow version, so maybe it's within that flow? I've also gotten that error when the flow was trying to do something but when it edited a record it kicked off a workflow update that failed so the flow failed.

Comment: @DanWooding I have checked the version and name. The flow name is different.

Comment: Process Builder are also a type of Flow (they report as Flow errors when Things Go Wrong). Do you have any active Process Builders on the object(s) in question?

Comment: @sfdcfox It is a process builder. Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flows and Process Builder both use the same underlying engine to perform, and therefore suffer from similar limitations, like consuming CPU governor limits. This shared engine is what makes it possible (from a technology standpoint) for Process Builder to call Flows and @InvocableMethod Apex Code. Instead of reinventing the wheel, they simply repurposed it. Both the on-screen errors and the errors emailed to administrators will call a Process Builder a Flow, and have similar characteristics that makes it (probably) impossible to tell the difference between the two. So, whenever you encounter this error, administrators should check the Process Builder page as well as the Flow page, since the error could have come from either area.